# Python Memory error on scipy stats. Scipy linalg lstsq <> manual beta

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, out-of-memory, linear-regression

Not sure if this question belongs here or on crossvalidated but since the primary issue is programming language related, I am posting it here.

Inputs:

Y= big 2D numpy array (300000,30)

X= 1D array (30,)

Desired Output:

B= 1D array (300000,) each element of which regression coefficient of regressing each row (element of length 30) of Y against X

So `B[0] = scipy.stats.linregress(X,Y[0])[0]`

I tried this first:

```
B = scipy.stats.linregress(X,Y)[0]
```

hoping that it will broadcast X according to shape of Y. Next I broadcast X myself to match the shape of Y. But on both occasions, I got this error:

```
    File "C:\...\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 3011, in linregress
        ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
    File "C:\...\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1766, in cov
        return (dot(X, X.T.conj()) / fact).squeeze()
  MemoryError
```

I used manual approach to calculate beta, and on Sascha's suggestion below also used scipy.linalg.lstsq as follows

```
B = lstsq(Y.T, X)[0] # first estimate of beta
Y1=Y-Y.mean(1)[:,None]
X1=X-X.mean()
B1= np.dot(Y1,X1)/np.dot(X1,X1) # second estimate of beta
```

The two estimates of beta are very different however:

```
>>> B1
Out[10]: array([0.135623, 0.028919, -0.106278, ..., -0.467340, -0.549543, -0.498500])
>>> B
Out[11]: array([0.000014, -0.000073, -0.000058, ..., 0.000002, -0.000000, 0.000001])
```

Answer (score 1):

Scipy's [linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) will output slope+intercept which defines the regression-line.

If you want to access the coefficients naturally, scipy's [lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html) might be more appropriate, which is an equivalent formulation.

Of course you need to feed it with the correct dimensions (your data is not ready; needs preprocessing; swap dims).

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lstsq
Y = np.random.random((300000,30))
X = np.random.random(30)
x, res, rank, s = lstsq(Y.T, X)  # Y transposed!
print(x)
print(x.shape)
```

#### Output

```
[  1.73122781e-05   2.70274135e-05   9.80840639e-06 ...,  -1.84597771e-05
   5.25035470e-07   2.41275026e-05]
(300000,)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Somehow I am getting different results on using this and my approach. I have added the details in my question above.